# Invalidated references to members of polymorphic objects

Tags: c++, c++11

Say I have two classes `Foo` and `Bar` inheriting the interface `Base` and want to store instances of these classes in a vector of type `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>`. An object of `Bar` type should store a reference to a value (which, in this scenario, is a member of the `Foo` class). Conceptually, I want to achieve the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

template<typename Type, typename ... Types>
std::unique_ptr<Type> make_unique(Types &&... arguments) {
    return std::unique_ptr<Type>(new Type(std::forward<Types>(arguments)...));
}

class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() = 0;
    virtual void execute() = 0;
};

Base::~Base() {
}

class Foo: public Base {
public:
    void execute() override {
        // Foo-specific implementation of execute(), may change value_
        value_ = 2;
    }
    const int & value() const { 
        return value_; 
    }
private:
    int value_;
};

class Bar: public Base {
public:
    Bar(const int &value) : value_(value) {}
    void execute() override {
        // Bar-specific implementation of execute(), uses current value_
        std::cout << value_ << std::endl;
    }
private:
    const int &value_; // Reference to a value, not necessarily from Foo
};

int main() {
    // Collection of base objects, possibly inside another object
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> baseVector;
    baseVector.emplace_back(make_unique<Foo>());
    baseVector.emplace_back(make_unique<Bar>(
        dynamic_cast<Foo *>(baseVector.back().get())->value()));
    for (auto &base : baseVector)
        base->execute();

    return 0;
}
```

However, the `dynamic_cast` feels very smelly to me (I know I could also use a `static_cast` but that is not much better, I guess). An alternative to avoid the `dynamic_cast` would be to change the `Foo` class to look like

```
class Foo: public Base {
public:
    Foo() : value_(new int()) {}
    void execute() override {
        // Foo-specific implementation of execute(), may change value_
        *value_ = 2;
    }
    const int & value() const { 
        return *value_; 
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<int> value_;
};
```

and then do

```
int main() {
    // Collection of base objects, possibly inside another object
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> baseVector;
    auto foo = make_unique<Foo>();
    auto *fooPtr = foo.get();
    baseVector.emplace_back(std::move(foo));
    baseVector.emplace_back(make_unique<Bar>(fooPtr->value()));
    for (auto &base : baseVector)
        base->execute();

    return 0;
}
```

But also this does not seem to be very elegant. How to deal with situations like these in an appropriate manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it in a more pedestrian way that would be fairly readable:

```
struct Base { virtual ~Base() = default; /* ...*/ };
struct Foo : Base { int x_; int & value() { return x_; /* ...*/ };
struct Bar : Base { int & r_; Bar(int & r) : r_(r) {} /* ...*/ };

auto foo = std::make_unique<Foo>();
auto bar = std::make_unique<Bar>(foo->value());

v.push_back(std::move(foo));
v.push_back(std::move(bar));
```

Just because `emplace_back` exists doesn't mean you have to use it for absolutely everything!

Comment: [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) is C++14.

Comment: @Zereges: Since `std::make_unique` is C++14, I provided my own implementation of `make_unique`.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Ok, yours looks a bit more elegant now, indeed. But your solution as well as my second alternative require the `value_` member of the `Foo` class to be of type `std::unique_ptr<int>`. Otherwise, the reference would become invalid as soon as the `Foo` instance is moved to the vector. Is `std::unique_ptr` really my only option here?

Comment: @Marcel: I'm sorry, I don't understand any of your concerns. Your vector is meant to hold a polymorphic collection, so it needs to be a vector of unique pointers. There aren't any other unique pointers in the scenario, and nothing gets invalidated... what am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, you don't miss anything - my fault. Accepted your answer.

Comment: @Zereges are planty of polyfill of this lack of C++11, almost oneliner solution in this [patch](https://lists.launchpad.net/kicad-developers/msg27281.html)

Comment: @sfiore: Or you could use `absl::make_unique` from [Abseil](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp).

Comment: @patch I just pointed out that, since OP tagged his question as [tag:c++11].